# Build failing - woff2 format

Tags: css, build, fonts, gulp, spfx

I have only gulp file, I don't have webpack file.
I have this issue when trying to run gulp serve, woff2 file can't be loaded:

```
Error - [webpack] 'dist':
./lib/webparts/kukCssFix/components/css/482a5ce5cc2d6708aee6f23df25886d6.woff2
Module parse failed: C:\Projects\kuktest\kukCssSoluton\lib\webparts\kukCssFix\components\css\482a5ce5cc2d6708aee6f23df25886d6.woff2 Unexpected character '' (1:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

This is configuration of gulpfile.js. I tried to add task for it but that doesn't work:

```
'use strict';

const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');
const gulp = require('gulp');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
gulp.task('copy-fonts', function () {
    return gulp.src([
    './src/webparts/kukCssFix/components/css/*.woff',
    './src/webparts/kukCssFix/components/css/*.woff2'
  ])
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/kukCssFix/fonts'));
```

});

```
build.addSuppression(`Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`);

build.initialize(require('gulp'));
```

This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "kuk-css-soluton",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "build:prod": "gulp clean --ship && gulp build --ship && gulp bundle --ship && gulp package-solution --ship"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "15.6.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.4.1",
    "@types/react": "15.6.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.6",
    "@types/webpack-env": ">=1.12.1 <1.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.4.1",
    "@types/chai": ">=3.4.34 <3.6.0",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/mocha": ">=2.2.33 <2.6.0",
    "@types/react": "15.6.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.6",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

What should I do?